# Combile two multidimensional list into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists that I wanted to merge:

```
list1 = [['desktop', '10022'], ['mobile', '119'], ['tablet', '7']]
list2 = [['desktop', '9964'], ['mobile', '117'], ['tablet', '8']]
```

I wanted to arrange them into this list:

```
new_list = [('desktop', ['10022', '9964']), ('mobile', ['119', '117']), ('tablet', ['7', '8'])]
```

then, I also wanted to compute the percentage difference between the integers and insert the answer in the list:

```
updated_list = [['desktop', '10022', '9964', '0.5821'], ['mobile', '119', '117', '1.7094'], ['tablet', '7', '8', '-12.5']]
```

Here's my rough code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list1 = [['desktop', '10022'], ['mobile', '119'], ['tablet', '7']]
list2 = [['desktop', '9964'], ['mobile', '117'], ['tablet', '8']]

merged = OrderedDict()

for list_ in list1, list2:
    for k, v in list_:
        try:
            merged[k].append(v)
        except:
            merged[k] = [v]

def diff(x, y):
    return ((x/y)-1)*100

updated_list = [[row,x,y,diff(x,y) for x,y in vals.items()] for row,vals in merged.items()]
```

Can't get this thing to work :(

Comment: Are corresponding items always in the same position?

Comment: Is order guaranteed for `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: If the order  assumption is violated, use a `defaultdict`

Comment: Do not use `except:` without specifying exception. This can be dangerous when an error is silenced down.

Comment: @StevenSummers yes, the order is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your lists is sorted and homogeneous, you can

```
[[k, int(v1), int(v2), int(v1)/int(v2) - 1] for ((k, v1), (_, v2)) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If lists data is homogeneous, but not sorted, simply call

```
list1.sort()
list2.sort()
```

prior to processing it. If data is not homogeneous, simple way to iterate over is to cast lists to dictionaries and iterate over common keys:

```
d1, d2 = dict(list1), dict(list2)
[[k, int(d1[k]), int(d2[k]), int(d1[k])/int(d2[k]) -1] for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()]
```

Comment: Your first line throws up a `SyntaxError`, and the numeric values in his data are strings, so they need to be converted before you can calculate the percentage. So, it should probably be: `[[k, int(v1), int(v2), int(v1)/int(v2) - 1] for ((k, v1), (_, v2)) in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working code:

```
# The same, and then

updated_list = [(row, vals[0], vals[1], diff(int(vals[0]), int(vals[1]))) for row, vals in merged.items()]
print(updated_list)
```

Your problem was that you wanted to unpack `x` and `y` from `vals`, but you can't do that unless `vals` is a list of `tuples`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
updated_list = [[row,x,y,diff(x,y) for x,y in vals.items()] for row,vals in merged.items()]
```

`vals` is a list, so it has no method `items()`, the inner list-comprehension has a syntax error and would not work even if it were `[(row,x,y,diff(x,y) )for x,y in vals.items()]` or some such, because of the wrong method call. Also you wouldn't unpack a list of 2 with `for x,y in vals`. You'd unpack a list of 2-tuples like that, for example.

This'll deviate from what you've tried, but you could create an ordered default dict, merge, and do your calculations:

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict):
   ...:     def __missing__(self, key):
   ...:         obj = self[key] = self.default_factory()
   ...:         return obj
   ...:     def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwgs):
   ...:         super().__init__(*args, **kwgs)
   ...:         self.default_factory = default_factory
   ...:         

In [11]: list1 = [['desktop', '10022'], ['mobile', '119'], ['tablet', '7']]

In [12]: list2 = [['desktop', '9964'], ['mobile', '117'], ['tablet', '8']]

In [14]: merged = OrderedDefaultDict(list)

In [16]: from itertools import chain

In [17]: for k, v in chain(list1, list2):
    ...:     merged[k].append(v)
    ...:     

In [18]: merged
Out[18]: OrderedDefaultDict([('desktop', ['10022', '9964']), ('mobile', ['119', '117']), ('tablet', ['7', '8'])])

In [19]: def diff(x, y):
   ....:     return ((x/y)-1)*100                                                                                          
   ....: 

In [20]: [[k, x, y, str(diff(float(x), float(y)))]
    ...:  for k, (x, y) in merged.items()]
Out[20]:                                                                                                                                    
[['desktop', '10022', '9964', '0.5820955439582498'],                                                                                        
 ['mobile', '119', '117', '1.7094017094017033'],                                                                                                   
 ['tablet', '7', '8', '-12.5']]
```

Or format the floats as you see fit, for example

```
'{:.4f}'.format(diff(...))
```